# Does the Black Ops 2 Season Pass include the additional Ray Gun Mark II & Peacekeeper weapons?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

When you buy the season pass for Black Ops 2, do you still get the Ray Gun Mark II and the Peacekeeper? I have read a lot of answers and it only talks about the map packs included but what about the weapons?

Comment: Have u bought the season pass JohnoBoy?

Answer (score 3):

The Black Ops 2 season pass includes all four map packs, including *Revolution*, which contains the Peacekeeper & *Vengeance* which contains the Ray Gun Mark II.

[Source](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Call_of_Duty:_Black_Ops_II#Downloadable_Content)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does actually because with the season pass, you can get all 4 new map packs, and the two guns you are talking about, Peacekeeper and Ray Gun Mark 2 come with two of the map packs that you get for free with the season pass. I Also believe you can get any of the camos with the season pass.